# Vb.net PrintWriter prints nothing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing, vb.net-2010, printwriter

I'm developing an application in vb.net. The output form is shown below. It has a PRINT button to print the components in the form. I mean it should print the entire form when I click the print button. I wrote the following code on the PRINT button

```
PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        PrintDocument1.Print()
End If
```

But the problem is it doesn't print the form. Instead, it prints a blank page.

Can someone say what is the mistake in my code, and how to print the page like the above image. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution

Instead of using PrintDialog and PrintDocument, use PrintForm control.

and the code should be

```
On Error GoTo handler
    PrintForm1.Print()
    Exit Sub
handler:
    MsgBox("error")
```

Now my problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

STEP1 : Import your namespace as
            Imports System.Drawing.Printing

STEP2 : AT VISUALBASIC POWERPACKS AND USE "PrintForm" tool from ToolBox.

STEP3 : CREATE A BUTTON AND DOUBLE CLICK IT AND COPY THE FOLLOWING CODE

```
         PrintForm1.PrintAction = PrintAction.PrintToPreview
         PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.FullWindow)
```